# Release build crashing on Fast, Whole Module Optimization settings

Tags: objective-c, release-builds, ios10.3, swift3, xcode8

I have an app which contains both swift and Objective C code and it crashes at a specific point only on release build mode if I set the optimization level to `Fast, Whole Module Optimization` and on log it gives me error and there are no other logs

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x15de80f08: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

If I set the optimization level to `Fast, Single File Optimization`, it works just fine.

I can't seem to pin point the part of code that causes crash on `Fast, WMO`
setting. When I took the device log from Xcode, its coming as an unsymbolicated crash log. Can you give me some directions to troubleshoot and fix this issue? Why does it crash with WMO settings and not on with SFO setting?

Comment: Show the crash details.

Comment: Its coming as an unsymbolicated crash log, is there any other way to take symbolicated logs?

Comment: That makes it a bit more difficult.   :)

Still, the crash log may be informative.